# Optimizing a query with multiple IN

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, database-administration

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE department='param1' AND type='param2' AND product='param3'
AND product_code IN (10-30 alphanumerics) AND unit_code IN (10+ numerics)
AND first_name || last_name IN (10-20 names)
AND sale_id LIKE ANY(list of regex string)
```

Runtime was too high so I was asked to optimize it.

The list of parameters varies for the code columns for different users.
Each user provides their list of codes and then loops over product.
product used to be an IN clause list as well but it was split up.

**Things I tried**

By adding an index on (department, type and product) I was able to get a 4x improvement.
Current runtime is that some values of product only take 2-3 seconds, while others take 30s.

Tried creating a pre-concat'd column of first_name || last_name, but the runtime improvement was too small to be worth it.

Is there some way I can improve the performance of the other clauses, such as the "IN" clauses or the LIKE ANY clause?

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor schema design. Any time you find yourself with enumerated column names (above, say, 2) consider whether your design is optimal

Comment: Does enumerated column name refer to a1-a8? 
I was using those as placeholder names, the columns are all unique and meaningful.

Comment: Yes, in which case I'd be tempted to make the example slightly less abstract

Comment: I have tried to make it less abstract, unfortunately most of the IN clauses are just searching lists of alphanumeric id's

Comment: Are there business relationships across any of these columns?  For instance, can a `product` belong to more than one `type` or `department`?  Does `product_code` or `unit_code` relate to `product`?  When you say that some values of `product` cause the query to run 30 seconds, that sounds like you have a bunch of rows for that particular `product`.  Of all the things you are trying to match on, which one is the most restrictive and returns the least number of rows?

Comment: For the sake of this example, it would be something like:
Clothes (Department) -> Specific brand of shirt (Type) -> Size (product). I could have named it better. As you say, certain products have significantly more rows than others which is probably the reason for the slowdown as the "product" is not unique to the department + type.

For most restrictive, it would be one of the code columns, are you suggesting I split and index on that one?

Comment: Yes.  Please index the most restrictive column.  The `department` tipped me off that this is clothing retail since it sounds like merch hierarchy :-).  If `product` is unique, then there is no reason to index (`department`, `type`, `product`).  But if one of the code columns used in an `IN` comparison is more restrictive, then index that one.  Are you familiar with doing `explain analyze` on your queries?

Comment: Yeah product is not unique in this case. I did use EXPLAIN on the query, the previous admin had created a massive primary key of every single column. I noticed the engine was only using those three columns which was why I created that index initially. 
Should I add the IN column to the existing index or create an index with fewer columns?

Comment: Just a heads up that you need to @ me on your notes.  If you have the time, I would try it both ways.  First create an index with the column you have in mind, and see if it gets picked up in the plan.  If that works (or not), you can replace your existing index with that column added to it.  Please see the answer that @a_horse_with_no_name posted, too.

Comment: What version of PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience replacing large IN lists, with a JOIN to a VALUES clause often improves performance.

So instead of:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE department='param1' 
  AND type='param2' 
  AND product='param3'
  AND product_code IN (10-30 alphanumerics)
```

Use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
   JOIN ( values (1),(2),(3) ) as x(code) on x.code = t.product_code
WHERE department='param1' 
  AND type='param2' 
  AND product='param3'
```

But you have to make sure you don't have any duplicates in the `values ()` list

---

The concatenation is also wrong because the concatenated value is something different then comparing each value individually, e.g. `('alexander', 'son') would be treated identical to` ('alex', 'anderson')`

You should use:

```
and (first_name, last_name) in ( ('fname1', 'lname1'), ('fname2', 'lname2'))
```

This can also be written as a join

```
SELECT * 
FROM table t
  JOIN ( values (1),(2),(3) ) as x(code) on x.code = t.product_code
  JOIN ( 
     values ('fname1', 'lname1'), ('fname2', 'lname2') 
  ) as n(fname, lname) on (n.fname, n.lname) = (t.first_name, t.last_name)
WHERE department='param1' 
  AND type='param2' 
  AND product='param3'
```

Comment: I shouldn't have used first_name, last_name, as I was trying to think up a good approximation for the concat, but it is a non-issue as a unique integer is also appended to the end.

Comment: @finiteisaac: regardless of what exactly you are comparing, the concatenation is always wrong.

Comment: I was talking about the concatenation, which is actually a string and integer and not first and last name. I was trying to make up some logical approximation for the actual schema but obviously this conversion didn't work out. Would it be faster to compare them like you have shown rather than concat'ing them though?

Comment: @finiteisaac: performance isn't relevant, the concatenation is simply going to return incorrect results (although I do think it might be slightly faster)

Comment: Sorry, let me make myself clear. The first_name column is the name (alphabetical), and the last_name column is only special characters and numbers. Your answer did make me curious whether it is worth concatenating them or checking them separately however.

Comment: It's always worth checking them separately because that's the only correct way to do it.

Comment: The current list provided looks like this: abcde_123
It would require some work to manually split the input list of names, will there be a worthwhile performance increase?

Answer (score 0):

You generally don't have to do anything special to enable an index for it to be used with multiple IN-lists, other than keep the table well vacuumed and analyzed.  A btree index on  `(department, type, product, product_code, unit_code, (first_name || last_name))` should work well.  If it doesn't, please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` for it, preferably with `track_io_timing` turned on.  If the selectivities of each of your conditions are not mostly independent of each other, that might lead to planning problems.